# Do any OAuth grants support granting access on behalf of a user, without requiring user interaction?

Tags: oauth-2.0

We have some web services, and an OAuth2 server that protects access to them.

I want our outside clients to be able to use these web services in their mobile apps. But in some cases, they want to maintain their own login/password database, and not require the user to authenticate separately to our web services. In that case the client has identifiers for users on our side that correspond to their own users (we sync these up outside of the OAuth process).

So, assuming the users have already established a session on the client's side, I want to be able to give them some kind of access token that will grant them access to the corresponding user on our side, without prompting them for a separate password. How can I do this?

One approach would be to require the clients to set up a proxy to our web services, protected by their own session. Their mobile apps would send requests to the proxy server instead of our web services directly. Their server could use the [client-credentials grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4) to get an access token, and add it to any incoming requests before proxying them to our server.

Is there a better way? This seems kind of difficult for clients to implement, and you'd have to verify somehow that the incoming requests aren't trying to access data for a different user.

Is there any grant that would allow the client's server to request an access token on behalf of an individual user, without the user's interaction? Then maybe the token could be returned to the app, and the app could use it to access our web services directly. With the client-credentials grant, the token gives access to all users, so it's not safe to return to an individual user's app.

Comment: Who are these clients? With-in Organization or outside? How are they identifying the user? Generally, you have `password`  grant type flow. A use case will be helpful to suggest.

Comment: @AbhishekTyagi Outside clients. They have identifiers for users in our system, but not passwords. I added some detail to the beginning of the question...hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to user's resource without user login or consent is anti-oauth(doesn't matter if it is 1.0a or 2.0). Hence there is no grant_type to support this directly.

Also the proposal of proxy, may not be a good idea for 2 reason.

1. Security: That proxy will open a gaping hole acoross your systems,
   that knowning a user's email, an attack can get all the data from
   your system.
2. Maintanebility: How would you keep track of authorization that the
   client credentials token had access to a certain email across
   system? This may create unnecessary checkpoints in your application(s).

Now, to here is a proposed solution which may work without changing much of your application

Please note it will be good idea to enable 2 way mutual auth or some form of additional security for verification.

[image: Proposed solution]

Let me know if this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. That's actually pretty close to what I ended up doing, so it's nice to have some validation. Regarding your first point -- doesn't the client credentials grant sort of allow access to users' data without their consent? The spec seems kind of vague on this point, but I assumed it could be used to give a client some kind of admin privileges, which could include access to user data. I agree about the proxy; we quickly abandoned that idea.

Comment: `doesn't the client credentials grant sort of allow access to users' data without their consent`. 

No, it doesn't.  Nowhere in the `client_cred` flow OAuth is aware of the user. only 3 other regular `grant_type` know user (implicit, auth_code & password). That is why I suggested a custom endpoint from which uses a designated client_id can ask for a token for a user from OAuth provider. Also, client_cred  authorization is time-bound, that is, client do not get refresh token. With implicit/password for your use case you can get a refresh_token, hence a longer user session.